# Bitrise Cert upload not finding Certs

Tags: xcode, bitrise

I’m trying to upload my certs to Bitrise by using the `codesigndoc` tool, which I’m running with the following command

bash -l -c "$(curl -sfL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitrise-tools/codesigndoc/master/_scripts/install_wrap-xcode.sh) --scheme='my Scheme' --certs-only"

The issue is that it’s not detecting any distribution certificates

```
The Xcode archive used development certificate: iPhone Developer: Me (XXX) [1234].
Please select a distribution certificate:
Please select from the list:
(type in the option's number, then hit Enter) [1] :
```

It errors out if I try and continue, with an invalid option response (if I just try to put in 1 or 0).

I already archived and exported the ipa manually, which I heard is sometimes needed.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue in `codesigndoc` - tracking it at: https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/no-codesigndoc-distribution-certificatea/4355

Will report the progress there.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to circumvent the problem by removing the `scheme` & `certs-only` flags.

Not sure why, but it fixed the problem.